# Is robocopy syncing files, copying them or syncing with the right parameter?

Tags: sync, robocopy

I want to do something like this
https://www.ubackup.com/synchronization/robocopy-two-way-sync-8523.html
I got the impression that robocopy is syncing.

That is it looks like if the file is older or newer and always replace older files with newer files.

However, others say that robocopy is copying file. So file in destination will be replaced whether it's newer or older

Which one is right?

I am thinking of using /e and /z parameter but nothing in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

says whether /e and /z means they are syncing or copying.

Microsoft official page says they're copying. Nothing in that page says that robocopy will check first if the file on the destination is older or newer.

I used robocopy once and sometimes I got things like skipped, older, and newer.

I can understand replacing old copies with "newer" copies but older?

```
I did some bat files
robocopy "arbitrage3" "arbitrage4" /e /z 
robocopy "arbitrage4" "arbitrage3" /e /z

echo Sync Complete

pause (It prevents the console window from closing after executing the command.)
```

> ```
>                      212    C:\Users\TeguhProg\Dropbox\arbitrage3\
>       *EXTRA File             129966        System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.xml 100%        New File
> ```
>
> 130        bitcoinopportunities24.xml 100%        New File
> 106251        bitcoinopportunities26.deps.json 100%        New File
> 738816        bitcoinopportunities26.dll 100%        New File
> 6793        bitcoinopportunities26.dll.config 100%        New File
> 154624        bitcoinopportunities26.exe 100%        New File
> 275324        bitcoinopportunities26.pdb 100%        New File
> 358        bitcoinopportunities26.runtimeconfig.json 100%        New
> File              106251        bitcoinopportunities27.deps.json 100%
> New File              781312        bitcoinopportunities27.dll 100%
> New File                6793        bitcoinopportunities27.dll.config
> 100%        New File              154624
> bitcoinopportunities27.exe 100%        New File              280480
> bitcoinopportunities27.pdb 100%        New File                 358
> bitcoinopportunities27.runtimeconfig.json 100%        Older
> 609503        checkthisurl.txt 100%        Older
> 496139        coinmarketcap.txt 100%        Older
> 375        Currencydata.txt 100%        Older                    178
> desktop.ini 100%        Newer                   8264
> emulatethese.txt 100%        Older                 13.9 m
> First5000Coins.txt 100%        Older                 211489
> GridFilledOrderReport30.txt 100%        Older                 208262
> GridFilledReportsGroupedbyPair30.txt 100%        Older
> 211289        GridTradeReport30.txt 100%        Older
> 3.5 m        log.txt 100%        Older                      0        marketlist.txt 100%        Older                 581771
> markettocoin.txt 100%        Older                 609465
> newlines.txt 100%        Older                  69271
> oparbitragestraight1000.txt 100%        Older                  45603
> oparbitragestraight10000.txt 100%        Older                  40547
> oparbitragestraight20000.txt 100%        Older                  30991
> oparbitragestraight50000.txt 100%        Older                 610553
> opbuylowsellhigh1000.txt 100%        Older                 492255
> opbuylowsellhigh10000.txt 100%        Older                 235368
> opbuylowsellhigh20000.txt 100%        Older                  87001
> opbuylowsellhigh50000.txt 100%        Older                  68265
> oplowSigDigit1000.txt 100%        Older                  43989
> oplowSigDigit10000.txt 100%        Older                  22007
> oplowSigDigit20000.txt 100%        Older                  10153
> oplowSigDigit50000.txt 100%        Older                 12.8 m
> opportunities.txt 100%        Older                 461913
> orders.txt 100%        Older                  44416        pairs.txt
> 100%        Newer                      0
> priceofbasecurrencies.txt 100%        Older                 187126
> pricestep.txt 100%        Older                 235385
> simplegridtrade2.txt 100%        Newer                 242805
> simplegridtrading.txt 100%        Older                  3.0 m
> tentative.txt 100%        New File                 165
> ~$indodax.xlsx

Some comments say that only difference between robocopy and normal copy is that robocopy skip similar files (with same date and size). What about if source is older in the source file, will it replace the newer file in the destination?

If robocopy skip similar files then the only difference between robocopy and normal copy is the speed of copying.

A comment says I need to add /xo to exclude older files but it's not specified anywhere. Obviously if I want to sync I got to add /xo so the newer file "prevail" whether it's in destination or in the source.

But nothing clearly says that. This links doesn't say it https://www.ubackup.com/synchronization/robocopy-two-way-sync-8523.html

Comment: It depends on the parameters you use. By default Robocopy will use the file size and date and potentially file attributes to determine if a file has changed and whether or not to copy but that can be changed by the parameters you use. What exact command line are you using?

Comment: You can also check the robocopy log output. It will show "skipped" for files it has not bothered to copy for one reason or another.

Comment: In one log I see older and newer. Most of the time they moved newer files but occasionally they copy "older" files.

Comment: I am thinking of using /e and /z parameter. Nothing on that parameter says whether it's syncing or copying/

Comment: I update the question to address the comment

Comment: If you need specific control then there are lots of options such as `/XO :: eXclude Older files.` robocopy is a complex tool with lots of edge cases. It would be better to describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: So basically without /xo robocopy will just only copy and won't care if the files in the destination is older or newer?

Comment: It *should* care but by default it simply checks whether they are *different* and then copies the file that has changed to the destination. Older or newer is not tested unless you start going down into the options. The default is basically "make the destination the same as the source" and only copies what is needed for that to happen. Robocopy is not an intelligent two way sync tool unless you spend time setting it up as such.

Comment: Can you turn that into an answer?

To be honest, with /XO I do not see why it's not a good syncing tool. That is what I want to know.

Comment: The problem is that your question here is now two distinctly different questions. The first question of whether robocopy copies everything is answered by the duplicate. Your second question of how make it behave the way you want should be a new question in my opinion.

Comment: Separating them is tricky. I mean I am actually surprised when I see that /XO command. Almost no website says you got to put /XO

Think about it.

Most say sync and copy interchangeably as if they're the same thing. This question clearly address that confusion. The other question is a different topic. The questions are related but they don't talk about what sync is, what copy is, what /XO is

Comment: The other question doesn't ask about syncing vs copying at all. It asks if it skips similar files by default, which is interesting. But that's still simply means faster copying.

Comment: And as I said, microsoft documentation, even the link I gave pretty much use sync and copy interchangeably. I think a page clearly saying, robocopy copies unless you use /xo option is needed. Otherwise many people will be confused like I was confused

Comment: The mistake you are making is in assuming the tool has any clue what exactly you want from it. The full tool name is **robust copy** so it's primary use is in copying one folder to another. It has a lot of options to configure *what* it is copying, and it can be bashed into being a rudimentary sync tool, but it requires knowledge and thought and the [robocopy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). Robocopy may be smart enough to only copy changed items, but beyond that it requires *you* to know what you don't want it to copy.

Comment: The xo option isn't a "fix to make it a sync tool", it is simply an option that happens to fit your desire not to copy files that are older than those in the destination. It still doesn't make it a sync tool because for that you would have to run robocopy in the opposite direction and copy changes back.

Comment: Yes. So 2 robocopy command. Worked for me. New files survive old files gone.